# How do i replace "+"(plus sign) with SPACE in my database?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sqlite

My database contains many + signs and i want to replace it with white-space....
What should be the query for that ?

Comment: Are you using mysql, oracle *and* sqlite?

Comment: Do you want to replace "+" with " " over all columns and rows of all tables? Or in a specific column of a specific table?

Comment: fortunately all 3 use the same function name and signature

Comment: Is this a symptom of a wider problem, that you didn't properly url-decode the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update tbl set column = replace(column, '+', ' ')
```

This updates all '+'s in the column named "column" in the table named "tbl" to a single white space, one for each "+"

If you only need to select for display, then same function, e.g.

```
select replace(column, '+', ' ') column, other1, col3
from tbl
```

Answer (score 2):

update TABLE_NAME set FIELD_NAME = replace(FIELD_NAME, ‘+’,‘ ’);

[Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle: [REPLACE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions153.htm#sthref1473)

Comment: Hey Rob, we both posted exactly 42 seconds ago!

Comment: What a coincidence, indeed! I should probably wait a few more minutes with these very basic questions. The different answers don't provide much additional value ...

Comment: Yeah. in fact I'm deleting my onene, as the thread leader has enhanced his answer with the one bit of additional information in mine.